Company trying to move my finishing date forward
I work for a small startup as a permanent employee. I have been there for over a year and thus am only required to give 1 months notice. Earlier this year I made the decision with my wife to relocate home (another country). I knew that the company was looking to control cashflow and as a result I informed them of this plan. Telling them that I would not be seeking to continue working for them once I relocated. They asked me what my desired finish date would be and I gave them a date 4 months out. They have since been trying to "negotiate" this with me. And today I was informed that they want me to finish 6 weeks from now.
I have not formally resigned (I'm based in Ireland so the intent to relocate may serve as my notice). Either way, this push by them feels like dismissal. And not a resignation on my part.

What did they "negotiate"? What was their offer? What could they do if you don't take said offer?

What’s the problem with them changing your notice period from 4 months to 6 weeks? You are probably right it is an informal dismissal date, but you plan to leave, and it sounds like you already gave them notice if that intention. By moving to online 6 weeks you’re both free to locate other opportunities. They have effectively chosen NOT to place you on garden leave for the difference of that time


I work for a small startup as a permanent employee. I have been there
for over a year and thus am only required to give 1 months notice.
Earlier this year I made the decision with my wife to relocate home
(another country). I knew that the company was looking to control
cashflow and as a result I informed them of this plan. Telling them
that I would not be seeking to continue working for them once I
relocated. They asked me what my desired finish date would be and I
gave them a date 4 months out.

You tried to do something that you thought would help your company. You also thought they wouldn't shove you out the door early, because you gave them an end date.
What you did tell them is even if I am a good worker, super productive, in 4 months I will not be here. This helps them plan knowing that they can save somebody else if there must be cuts. They can also determine when would be the right tome to let you go.
The advice is always tell them only when you must tell them. If you have to give x days notice, then don't tell them 4x days in advance. Your plans could change. Telling them early lets them know you will be gone soon.

They have since been trying to "negotiate" this with me. And today I
was informed that they want me to finish 6 weeks from now.

If they are required to give you notice equal to your requirement, then be glad they are giving you 6 more weeks.

Appreciate the dose of cold perspective. You are right and it's the reality I need to face. I've been fortunate to have a 23 year career working for great companies, and it has made me naive or excessively optimistic in these matters. Its a business relationship and they operated on "latest market info"! :)

There's nothing factually incorrect here, but it doesn't address the question, which is whether the company selecting the departure date changes it from resignation to dismissal.  OP would be well-advised to query how it will be recorded and whether it will affect benefits or future letters of recommendation / employment history verification.  And if the response is undesirable, offer a new resignation letter that establishes the company's chosen date.
